# Write SQL query based on list items

Tags: sql, list

I would like to write an SQL query based on a list.
Each condition of this query must be a combination of every four elements of the list (four by four) except for the last 3 ones.

For example :

```
my_list = (column_customer, LIKE, John, OR, column_town, NOT LIKE, New York, AND, column_instrument, = ,piano)
```

and the result i'm looking for is something like :

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_customer LIKE 'John' OR column_town NOT LIKE 'New York' AND column_instrument = 'piano' "
```

the number of items in `my_list` can change each time.

The purpose is to create a multi criteria search with multiple entry boxes filled by the user.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is bad idea due to sql injection. I'd suggest to use parameters. I can't help you more, because of not enough of information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Wich kind of informations do you need ? 
If ever you have a solution despite of the risk of sql injection can you give me a hint ? It would help me a lot

Comment: See: [Configuring parameters and parameter data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types)